# django eventstream / channels return HTML

Tags: django, django-channels, event-stream, htmx

I have a working application where I use django-eventstream to show info/error messages to users. All works well with `send_event()`:

```
send_event("mychan", "message", msg)
```

but what I actually want to do is send some html directly to the frontend because I use [htmx](https://htmx.org). How can I make this work and circumvent the `DjangoJSONEncoder` used by `django-eventstream`?

```
send_event("mychan", "message", {"data": "<h1>tesst</h1>"})
```

leads to:

[image]

**Edit:** I am aware of the `json_encode = False` flag for `send_event()`, this products the same result:

```
send_event("mychan", "message", "<h1>tesst</h1>", json_encode = False)
```

leads to:

[image]

In the webdev console this looks as follows (this is the same as django's `mark_safe()` produces in a `httpresponse` object:

```
"<b>tesst</b>"
```

I don't want to clean away the double quotes with JS :)

**Edit2:** After some further digging I modified the source code of `django-eventstream` with a `print()` statement, that prints the event and the `json_encode` setting every time a message is sent to the frontend. With `json_encode = False` set, this leads to this output:

```
> event_type: message, data: <b>tesst</b>, json_encode: False
> event_type: message, data: <b>tesst</b>, json_encode: True
> event_type: message, data: <b>tesst</b>, json_encode: True
> event_type: message, data: <b>tesst</b>, json_encode: True
> event_type: message, data: <b>tesst</b>, json_encode: True
```

I wrapped `send_event()` in a wrapper function that does a `print()` whenever it is executed, and I only see one `print` but multile SSE events result - only the first one takes `json_encode` into account.

The very ugly hack to set `json_encode = False` in the source code of `django-eventstream` does work. But this seems like a very bad solution.

Answer (score 1):

The `send_event` function has a `json_encode` option that you can set to `False` to prevent the encoding - that should fix your issue.

Code: https://github.com/fanout/django-eventstream/blob/b52c7e494afa93ada9abc36b86c724d90f5690b9/django_eventstream/eventstream.py#L14

Comment: thanks for your comment, and sorry for not writing that in my question before, but I know of this option and already tried it. I also edited my post to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

Django has [`mark_safe`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/utils/#django.utils.safestring.mark_safe) method, which works great for html in django admin table cells, which would normally remove html tags.

From the docs:

> **mark_safe(s)**
> Explicitly mark a string as safe for (HTML) output purposes. The returned object can be used everywhere a string is appropriate.
> Can be called multiple times on a single string.
> Can also be used as a decorator.
> For building up fragments of HTML, you should normally be using django.utils.html.format_html() instead.

I'm not sure about your case, but it's worth trying, as well as `django.utils.html.format_html` as stated above.

Comment: *This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. It should be a comment.*

Comment: If I wasn't honest and left out a part where I'm not sure, it would count as a valid answer, regardless if it works or not. Also, it can help others who struggle with formatting HTML on various places. Should I delete answer and post a comment, not sure what to do in this situation?

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. But as I mentioned, the problem lies within the implementation (or my usage) of the `send_event()` function. My code **is** correctly interpreted as html, as the image shows with the corresponding webdev output. I will nevertheless highlight this aspect in my question.